# How to identify DB2 port number

Tags: java, database, db2

I have to make DB2 connection in java using port number.
Is there any command in DB2 or any way that can get the DB2 port number?

I have not used the default port 50000 while making DB2 connection as this port can be changed during DB2 installation.
Please suggest any DB2 command or any other alternative.

Comment: if you are on a linux box you can try `netstat -pn | grep -i db` to list all the ports DB2 is listening to.

Comment: I figured there would be something similar for Windows.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On the Windows DB2 server, open a DB2 Command Window and execute the command

```
db2 get database manager configuration | findstr /i svce
```

This should provide some output like:

```
 TCP/IP Service name                          (SVCENAME) = db2c_DB2
 SSL service name                         (SSL_SVCENAME) =
```

SVCENAME is the port that DB2 is listening on.  To resolve this name to an actual port number, you need to refer to the services file, which is located at `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\services`.

Comment: This only works for the current instance. It is necessary to attach to each instance in the server in order to know all ports for DB2 instances defined in the "services" file.

Comment: @DurgadasKamath Care to elaborate?

Comment: In the DB2 command editor that command gave me an error, but "get database manager configuration" (without leading "db" and without the piped command) worked. In there I could manually search for svcename.

Answer (score 18):

Go to DB2 command prompt.

Issue the command to get the db2 instance

Command :  **db2 get instance**

Issue the command to find the TCP/IP service name

Command :  **db2 get dbm cfg | grep SVCE**

**Example**

db2 get dbm cfg | grep SVCE

TCP/IP Service name                          (SVCENAME) = db2c_db2inst9
The TCP/IP service name is "**db2c_db2inst9**"

Use the  TCP/IP  service name to find the port number in the /etc/services file

Command :  **grep TCP/IPservicename /etc/services**

Change **TCP/IPservicename** with the current service name.

**Example**

grep db2c_db2inst9 /etc/services

db2c_db2inst9   50090/tcp

The DB2 instance is running on the port number **50090**

Comment: This worked for me just using: db2 get dbm cfg.  Then reading down a little I saw my port, it was 50000.

Answer (score 9):

On the Linux/Unix DB2 server, open a shell terminal and logon with the instance owner. Execute the below command:

```
        db2 "get dbm cfg"|grep -i svce
```

Like the answer of Ian Bjorhvde you show the TCP/IP Service name,
SVCENAME you can view in the file /etc/service .

Comment: This only works for the current instance. If is necessary to change to each instance in order to get the service name, and match it in the services file.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have different instances in your server, that means, DB2 is listening in different ports.
First, you have to list the instances in the server

```
db2ilist
```

You will get a set of instance names. For each one you have to get the port name

Windows

```
set DB2INSTANCE=instname
db2 get dbm cfg
```

Linux

```
export DB2INSTANCE=instname
db2 get dbm cfg
```

If you do not change the instance, you will only get the service name of the current instance.
Another way to get that information from the client is via the Configuration Assistant (db2ca). With advanced view, you right click on an instance, and then you will get the details of the instance: port number, service name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the ports of all the db2 instance installed on the machine (for Linux or AIX systems)

```
netstat -aan | grep -i db2
```

Comment: In my case, it returns nothing on AIX.  The string 'db2' is not associated with the port being listened.